# magento category order change in subcategory_listing.phtml

Tags: php, html, magento

My question is on how i can change the category sort of magento.
The default is:

```
ABCD
EFGH
IJKL
```

(Using code to get alignment right for understanding)

I need to change this to:

```
AEI
BFJ
CGK
DHL
```

(Using code to get alignment right for understanding)

How to do this?

```
<div class="category-products">
<ul class="products-grid">
<?php
$_categories=$this->getCurrentChildCategories();
if($_categories->count()):
$categorycount = 0;
foreach ($_categories as $_category):
if($_category->getIsActive()):
$cur_category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_category);
$catName = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getName();
if ($categorycount == 0){
$class = "first";
}
elseif ($categorycount == 3){
$class = "last";
}
else{
$class = "";
}
?>
<li class="item <?=$class?>">
<a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>"><img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$this->getCurrentCategory()->getThumbnail();?>" width="90" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>" /></a>
<h4><a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></h4></a>
</li>
<?php
endif;
if($categorycount == 2){
$categorycount = 0;
echo "</ul>\n\n<ul class=\"products-grid\">";
}
else{
$categorycount++;
}
endforeach;
endif;
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

I hope you can help me out.
That would mean the world to me!

Answer (score 0):

Several options.

1) Use the category position stuff built into magento to order your categories through the admin into the order you desire.

2) Create a new UL element every 4 categories and use CSS styling to display each UL in a column type format. e.g. create a UL element. Count the categories outputted within the UL and every 4 categories you close the UL and then open a new one. You can use the count % 4 == 0 (mod) function to determine if you need to output a new UL.

3) Modify the SQL being generated in the block which gets the categories to have an order by clause (This is not simple with the order you want).

Personally I would try step 2 first and fail back to step 1 if need be. It's not as if your ordering by a column value so adding the sort by to the collection may be troublesome.

Comment: Thank-you very much, i'm going for solution 2).
CSS is done. Now i need to determine the new output.
What i have trouble with. Tried several counts with / 4 to split
into four rows but no luck there. Can u help me out with the last part?